How to read in a .sf dataframe into python?
I have a file that ends in ‘.sf’ and I need to read this file into python using pandas
I have tried having a look inside the file and the structure of it which made me believe it was a HTML file but that did not help me whatsoever.

can you provide a sample of the content of the file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can directly use the pandas.read_html() function. This function reads HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.
with open('yourfile.sf', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    html_content = file.read()

dfs = pd.read_html(html_content)

df = dfs[0]
print(df)

this will get you the first table , if you want more you can modify it accordingly.
